# Logarithmic scale returns NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js, math, logarithm

I have issues creating a logarithmic scale in d3. The scale works fine if it is set to linear.

This works:

```
var myLinScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([50, 1150]);

console.log(myLinScale(71)); //output = 831
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
var myLogScale = d3.scale.log()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([50, 1150]);

console.log(myLogScale(71)); //output = NaN
```

What is wrong with the logarithmic scale?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### New solution (using D3 v5.8)

After more than 2 years this question finally has a D3-based answer that doesn't suggest removing 0 from the domain, as I did in my original answer (see below).

This is possible due to the new [Symlog scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleSymlog) in D3 v5.8, based on a [by-symmetric log transformation](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/John_Webber4/publication/233967063_A_bi-symmetric_log_transformation_for_wide-range_data/links/0fcfd50d791c85082e000000.pdf), which allows 0 in the domain.

So, using your domain and range without any modification:

```js
var myLogScale = d3.scaleSymlog()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([50, 1150]);

console.log(myLogScale(71));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Or even shorter, with the new scale constructors in D3 v5.8:

```js
var myLogScale = d3.scaleSymlog([0, 100], [50, 1150]);

console.log(myLogScale(71));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

---

#### Original answer (for D3 v3)

Change your domain so it doesn't include or cross zero:

```js
var myLogScale = d3.scale.log()
      .domain([1e-6, 100])//domain doesn't include zero now
      .range([50, 1150]);

console.log(myLogScale(71));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In the above demo I'm using `1e-6`, which is `0.000001`.

**Explanation:**

The logarithm of zero is undefined (or not defined). In base 10, for instance, log(0) is a number `x` so that 10 raised to the power of `x` is zero... that number, of course, doesn't exist. The limit, however, when we approach zero from the positive side is minus infinity.

In pure JavaScript:

```js
console.log("Log of 0 is: " + Math.log(0))
```

Thus, in JavaScript, `log(0)` is negative infinity, or minus infinity.

That being said, according to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleLog):

> a log scale must have either an exclusively-positive or exclusively-negative domain; the domain must not **include or cross zero**. (emphasis mine)