# How to use logarithm sampling if data are between 0 and 1 to create legend using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend, sampling, logarithm

I am creating an continuous legend(have created using linear gradient) using D3 for linear sampling. Now I have to use same legend for logarithm sampling. But my data are between 0 and 1 as shown below. I see that domain values for logarithm sampling cannot be zero(gives infinite) and for values in zero range suppose (0.1, 0.2 and so on) gives negative values. How can I use my data to create continuous legend using logarithm sampling.

```
My Data:

[
[0.0, 255, 0, 0],
[0.2, 255, 255, 0],
[0.4, 0, 255, 0],
[0.6, 0, 255, 255],
[0.8, 0, 0, 255],
[1.0, 255, 0, 255]
]
```

where 0.0, 0.2,0.4 and so on is the domain value and rest are rgb values for the point.

```
const colorScale = scaleLog().domain([min,max]); // in my case min and max are [0, 1]
const id = "linear-gradient-" + id + "0";
linearGradient = defs
.append("linearGradient")
.attr("id", id)
.attr("x1", "0%")
.attr("x2", horizontal ? "100%" : "0%")
.attr("y1", "0%")
.attr("y2", horizontal ? "0%" : "100%");

// append the color
linearGradient
.selectAll("stop")
.data(itemColor)
.enter()
.append("stop")
.attr("offset", function (data) {
return data.offset + "%";
})
.attr("stop-color", function (data) {
return data.color;
});

// draw the rectangle and fill with gradient
svgLegend
.append("rect")
.attr("x", 35)
.attr("y", horizontal ? 70 : 18)
.attr("width", horizontal ? "189" : 20)
.attr("height", horizontal ? 20 : "149")
.style("fill", "url(#" + currentIndex + ")");

// create tick
const horizontalAxisLeg = axisBottom(scaleLog().domain([min, max]).tickValues(colorScale.domain());
```

My legend looks something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/z7gn8p5t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for using `d3.scaleSymlog` instead of `d3.scaleLog` ([have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40438950/5768908)), there's no issue in using a log scale.

Here is your code with some changes, on the top you have the log scale, and below it I put a linear scale for comparison:

```js
const itemColor = [{
    offset: 0.0,
    color: "#ff0000"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.2,
    color: "#ffff00"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.4,
    color: "#00ff00"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.6,
    color: "#00ffff"
  },
  {
    offset: 0.8,
    color: "#0000ff"
  },
  {
    offset: 1.0,
    color: "#ff00ff"
  }
];

const svg = d3.select("svg");
const colorScale = d3.scaleSymlog().domain([0, 1]).range([0, 400]); // in my case min and max are [0, 1]
const colorScale2 = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range([0, 400]); // in my case min and max are [0, 1]
const id = "linear-gradient-0";
const linearGradient = svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", id)
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "100%")
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("y2", "0%");

// append the color
linearGradient
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data(itemColor)
  .enter()
  .append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(data) {
    return colorScale(data.offset) / 4 + "%";
  })
  .attr("stop-color", function(data) {
    return data.color;
  });

const linearGradient2 = svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "linear-gradient-1")
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "100%")
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("y2", "0%");

// append the color
linearGradient2
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data(itemColor)
  .enter()
  .append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(data) {
    return colorScale2(data.offset) / 4 + "%";
  })
  .attr("stop-color", function(data) {
    return data.color;
  });

// draw the rectangle and fill with gradient
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 18)
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .style("fill", "url(#linear-gradient-0)");

// create tick
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(10,45)").call(d3.axisBottom(colorScale));

// draw the rectangle and fill with gradient
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 88)
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .style("fill", "url(#linear-gradient-1)");

// create tick
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(10,115)").call(d3.axisBottom(colorScale2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for solution but just asking because I am using older version of D3 is there any other solution using scaleLog only ? My current version do not support scaleSymlog  and not sure if I can upgrade the version due to some other reason. Also can you explain colorScale2(data.offset) / 4, why we use divide by 4 ?

Comment: @coder91 That `/4` is there just because my rect is 400px wide. Regarding your issue, since you cannot use `d3.scaleSymlog`, what about starting at `1e-6` instead of zero?

Comment: As I am new to this concept, sorry for asking dumb questions. You mean using domain like [1e-6, 1] ? Then how will be my domain if my values are like  0.0, 0.2,0.4,0.8,1.0 ?

Comment: I have another case where my min and max value can be say 250(min) and 450(max) and I want legend to look exactly same and only changes should be the axis 0 and 1 must be replaced with mine(250) min and max(450). But If I try to change to domain [250, 450] then the whole legend will be filled with only one color.